# Ошибка при использовании слушателя Java

Tags: java, java-8

В класс `BubbleListener` (48-я строка) добавил код `implements ActionListener`, ниже в классе добавил:

```java
public void actionPerfomed (ActionEvent e) {
    for (Bubble b: bubbleList)
        b.update();
    repaint();
}
```

после чего у меня появилась ошибка: `The type BubblePanel.BubbleListener must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`, красным подчеркнуто название класса. Объясните, пожалуйста с чем связана данная ошибка и как её исправить. Сам я начал изучать программирование недавно. В интернете найти ответ мне не удалось.

```
public class BubblePanel extends JPanel {
    Random rand = new Random();
    ArrayList<Bubble> bubbleList;
    int size = 25;
    Timer timer;
    int delay = 33;
    // объединяет все классы и методы для работы
    public BubblePanel() {
        timer = new Timer(delay, new BubbleListener());
        bubbleList = new ArrayList<Bubble>();
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        //testBubble();
        addMouseListener(new BubbleListener());
        addMouseMotionListener(new BubbleListener());
        addMouseWheelListener(new BubbleListener());
        timer.start();
    }
    //прописан метод рисования пузырьков
    public void paintComponent (Graphics canvas) {
        super.paintComponent(canvas);
        //конструкция фор ~ для каждого объекта б типа Бабл в массиве бабл лист {объект б рисуется на холсте}
        for(Bubble b: bubbleList) {
            b.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    // тест пузырьков (отключен)
    public void testBubble() {
        for(int n = 0; n<100; n++) {
            int x = rand.nextInt(600);
            int y = rand.nextInt(400);
            int size = rand.nextInt(50);
            bubbleList.add(new Bubble(x, y, size));
        }   
        repaint();
    }

    //!!! в строчке кода расположенной ниже,подчеркнуто название класса как ошибка
    private class BubbleListener extends MouseAdapter implements ActionListener {
        public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e) {
            bubbleList.add(new Bubble (e.getX(), e.getY(), size));
            repaint();
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            bubbleList.add(new Bubble(e.getX(), e.getY(), size));
            repaint();
        }
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            //для одинаковой работы прокрутки колесика для разных систем
            if(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("MAC"))
                size += e.getUnitsToScroll();
            else
                size -= e.getUnitsToScroll();

            if(size < 3) {
                size = 3;   
            }
        }
        public void actionPerfomed (ActionEvent e) {
            for (Bubble b: bubbleList)
                b.update();
            repaint();
        }
    }
    //класс отвечающий за создание пузырьков
    private class Bubble {
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int size;
        private Color color;

        public Bubble (int newX, int newY, int newSize) {
            x = newX;
            y = newY;
            size = newSize;
            color = new Color(rand.nextInt(256),
                    rand.nextInt(256),
                    rand.nextInt(256),
                    rand.nextInt(256));
        }

        public void draw (Graphics canvas) {
            canvas.setColor(color);
            canvas.fillOval(x - size/2, y - size/2, size, size);
        }
        public void update() {
            y -= 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите код интерфейса `ActionListener`

Comment: Опечатка в названии метода, пропущена одна `r`, должно быть: `actionPerformed`.

Comment: @AlexRudenko, глаз-алмаз :) Предлагаю вам оформить это как ответ ;)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень стыдно за свою невнимательность